# Laravel undefined variable into blade after calling from JSON

Tags: php, json, laravel

I've Signup form in my website. It was properly submitting before. Now I wanted to submit my form using ajax and wanted to return a variable from controller into JSON that I will use into blade file.

The form is submitting and values are showing into database but after redirection, it returns error.

```
Undefined variable: seller in report blade
```

I tried to decode my variable to make it work but still the same error.

How would I make it work?

Report-Blade

```
 @foreach(json_decode($seller, true) as $row)

  <a  href="{{route('Report', $row->id) }}" >
    {{ __('Show Report of ')}} {{$row->car_title}}
  </a>

 @endforeach
```

Controller

```
$seller = Sellers::take(1)->latest()->get();
   
return response(view('report',array('seller'=>$seller)),200, ['Content-Type' => 
'application/json']);
```

JavaScript

```
$("#submit-all").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
     var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "{{ route('form_for_private_sellers') }}",
        data : $('#msform').serialize() + "&_token=" + _token,

        dataType: 'JSON',
        beforeSend: function(){
            // Show loading image
            $("#se-pre-con").show();
        },
        success: function(data) {
            window.location = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/report/";
        },
        complete:function(data){
            // Hide loading image
            $("#se-pre-con").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You would need Javascript to populate the returned results. Blade will not have access to something returned from an ajax request. Blade is parsed server side.

Comment: @user3532758
Could you please guide how would I do that as I have tried my best.

Comment: I'm not good with jquery but let me post an answer for you.

Comment: @user3532758
Please. Remember one thing, variable should be accessible into foreach() array that's super important for me.

Comment: wait, I might have spoken too soon. You are actually returning the entire report view.

Comment: @user3532758
Yep. I will be calling id and name from database through my variable $seller. Now it would make sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220810/discussion-between-user3532758-and-shaan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As understood from your comments,

```
window.location = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/report/";
```

will hit the route

```
Route::get('/report', function () {
  return view('report');
})->name('private_seller_report');
```

Report blade expects a variable named `$seller`, and it is not being sent from the route. You would need to change the route to something similar to this:

```
Route::get('/report', function () {
  $sellers = Seller::get(); //your logic
  return view('report', ['seller' => $sellers]);
})->name('private_seller_report');
```

Alternatively you can point the route to a method in a controller if you want to avoid bulking up your routes.

Comment: Perfect Approach. So I simply remove query and return statement from my controller and updated my route to your suggested one and It worked !...

Answer (score 1):

you need two route for this

first for rendering blade

```
return view('report');
```

and the second for fetch seller

```
$seller = Sellers::latest()->take(1)->get();
return $seller
```

Comment: We don't need to define two routes but what we can do is send variable in the same route like #user3532758 below. 
Still I will upvote your answer as you pointed me to correct direction. Only your code was missing.